# Таймер в методе java

Tags: java

Как создать таймер в методе boost, по истечению которого запустится метод stopboost?

Я поискал на стаке и нашел таймер, только не знаю, как им пользоваться.[Таймер.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817933/what-is-the-equivalent-to-a-javascript-setinterval-settimeout-in-android-java)

```
public void boost() {
    unboost = false;
    velocity.y = 200;
}

public void stopboost() {
    velocity.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Э,а почему мне значок "инвестор" не дали?

Comment: @danpetruk, а это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8694/danpetruk?tab=badges что?

Comment: А знаете, кто еще гонялся за значками? Адольф Гитлер.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Объясняю. Нам нужен класс [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), который создан для того, чтобы ставить отложенные задачи.

Метод [public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) работает достаточно просто. Второй аргумент `delay` — задержка в миллисекундах. Первый аргумент — экземляр объекта [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Этот абстрактный класс предельно прост и требует реализовать всего один метод:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {...}

}
```

Итак, нам нужен экземпляр этого класса. Как мы можем его получить? Проще всего объявить анонимный класс.

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() { 

    @Override
    public void run() {
         // тут наш код
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы использовать Timer, нужно создать его экземляр:

```
Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
```

Отдаем ему наш TimerTask:

```
timer.schedule(tt, 1000);
```

Если Timer нам больше не нужен, то мы можем и не присваивать его переменной, а выполнить метод на свежесозданном экземпляре и забыть о нем:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(tt, 1000);
```

Поскольку и TimerTask нам больше не нужен, то мы можем его создавать прямо в вызове метода:

```
public void boost() {

    //какой-то код метода

    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
        new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                stopboost();
            }
        }, 
    1000 );
    //дальше код метода
}

public void stopboost() {
    velocity.y = 0;
}
```

И наконец, если метод stopboost существует только ради этого таймера, то и его мы тоже исключим (inline это называется)

```
public void boost() {

    //какой-то код метода

    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
        new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
        }, 
    1000 );
    //дальше код метода
}
```

Answer (score 1):

а почему бы не сделать так

```
public void boost() {
    unboost = false;
    velocity.y = 200;

    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 это 1 секунда

      stopboost();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }


}

public void stopboost() {
    velocity.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы так весь поток останавливаете.

Comment: При таком подходе, основной поток просто зависает.

Comment: Вы правы, если это в основном потоке это проблема. это я не в основном потоке, предлогаю сделать а в rannable хотя бы.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev: в общем-то Timer примерно это и делает — запускает ждущий поток, который потом выполняет TimerTask.