# Как сделать задержку через timer?

Tags: c#, таймер

Есть метод(выводит значение ячейки массива), который нужно вызывать через определенные промежутки времени. Сначала делал как. В цикле делал перебор массива, вызов метода с i-м аргументом и ставил `Thread.Sleep(1000);` Сказали - нужно избавиться от `Sleep` и использовать таймер. Кинул таймер на форму, на событие нажатия кнопки повесил включение таймера(изначально выключен), внутренности цикла перенес в таймер, ввел новую переменную-индекс массива, которая в конце таймера увеличивается на 1 и в самом конце останавливаю таймер. Я не понимаю, как вызвать сам таймер несколько раз с промежутком прописанным в таймере. Он работает, но работает только один раз(по нажатию кнопки). И вот тут я встрял

Было

```
private void sayItButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    digit = onDigits(whatToSay.Text);
    if (digit.Count > 1 && //проверка на то, что у нас не число от 
    digit[digit.Count - 1] >= 1 //11 до 19, а то скажет 10 и 1, вместо 11
    &&
    digit[digit.Count - 2] == 10) {
        digit[digit.Count - 2] += digit[digit.Count - 1];
        digit.RemoveAt(digit.Count - 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < digit.Count; i++) //проходимся по коллекции и проверяем каждый элемент
    {
        if (digit[i] != 0) //проверка на нуль в начале
        {
            sayIt(digit[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    flag = true;
}
```

А стало

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (CurDig < digit.Count) {
        sayIt(digit[CurDig]);
        CurDig++;
    }
    timer1.Stop();
}

private void sayItButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    digit = onDigits(whatToSay.Text);
    if (digit.Count > 1 && //проверка на то, что у нас не число от 
    digit[digit.Count - 1] >= 1 //11 до 19, а то скажет 10 и 1, вместо 11
    &&
    digit[digit.Count - 2] == 10) {
        digit[digit.Count - 2] += digit[digit.Count - 1];
        digit.RemoveAt(digit.Count - 1);
    }
    while (CurDig < digit.Count - 1) {
        timer1.Start();
    }
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: Может, выложите кусок кода, который воспроизводит проблему? А то по словесному описанию код трудновато читать )

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил код до/после

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет этот ответ: [Таймер в методе java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446083)

Comment: @dr_zak: «Сказали нужно избавиться от Sleep» — это как-то по-детски. Вы как программист должны сами понимать, почему `Sleep` в принципе не подходит, и что нужно использовать вместо этого.

Comment: @VladD сказал препод, и я понимаю почему Sleep не подходит, просто пытался сначала сделать так как понял, а вот с таймером мне сказали позже. Я не смог разобраться с таймером и решил спросить здесь у гуру. Может быть вы что-то сможете подсказать?

Comment: @dr_zak: Я поддерживаю существующий ответ: вам нужен `async` и `await Task.Delay(...)`.

Comment: Вместо добавления `[Решено]` к заголовку следует принять ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо большое всем кто откликнулся: @Nick Volynkin, @VladD, @Pavel Mayorov, @IGOR.
Разобрался сам, посидел почитал про таймеры. Итог приведу ниже, может быть кому пригодится.
Сам таймер

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (digit[CurDig] != 0)                      //проверка на нуль в начале
    {
        sayIt(digit[CurDig]);
        CurDig++;
        if (CurDig == digit.Count)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            CurDig = 0;
        }               
    }

}
```

Кнопка

```
private void sayItButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag = true;
    digit = onDigits(whatToSay.Text);
    if (digit.Count > 1 &&                       //проверка на то, что у нас не число от 
        digit[digit.Count - 1] >= 1             //11 до 19, а то скажет 10 и 1, вместо 11
        && digit[digit.Count - 2] == 10)
    {
        digit[digit.Count - 2] += digit[digit.Count - 1];
        digit.RemoveAt(digit.Count - 1);
    }
    timer1.Start();                       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, вы несколько не понимаете, что такое таймер, раз пытаетесь запустить его несколько раз в цикле. Когда таймер работает, он "выкидывает" события-тики до тех пор, пока не будет остановлен. Вы его останавливаете сразу же - вот он и останавливается.

Теперь как вам исправить свой код.

1. Уберите цикл вокруг `timer1.Start();` - таймер достаточно запустить всего один раз. Кроме того, ваш цикл, в том виде как вы его привели - бесконечный, и на нем программа должна зависнуть...
2. Перед `timer1.Stop();` напишите `else`

PS Вообще говоря, задача идеально ложится на асинхронное программирование. Если есть возможность - попытайтесь использовать его вместо таймера. Все отличие от изначальной программы - в том, что перед `void` в обработчике нажатия кнопки пишите `async`, а `Thread.Sleep(1000)` заменяется на `await Task.Delay(1000)`. Плюс понадобится логика для блокировки повторного нажатия кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение!

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // метод выводящий значение ячейки массива
    }
```

Comment: Да и соглашусь с Павлом)) Для начала надо почитать по Timer!!!