# Время перед выполнением проверки в методе

Tags: java

Мне нужно в методе, в конструкции if, сделать проверку, что если с момента запуска метода прошло 30 секунда значит true.
Например :

```
public void test()  
{  
   Timer timer = new Timer(30); // типо 30 сек  
   if(timer == 0) // или может какой то метод есть который говорит что таймер офф  
    {
      sout("Работает");  
    }

}
```

Пробовал `Thread.sleep()`, но этот вариант останавливает всю программу, а мне нужно что бы проверка в методе выполнилась с задержкой.

Comment: а что мешает сделать новый поток и его уже остановить? или просто TimerTask сделать https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Я бы посоветовал более подробно описать задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить. Сейчас,  по крайней мере мне,  не понятно чего вы пытаетесь добиться таким способом.

Comment: @temq есть игра, есть метод на проверку вернулся ли NPC на свое место. Бывает игрок бьет NPC и убегает вместе с ним, иногда случаются моменты когда NPC не возвращается сам. По этому я хочу добавить проверку что если в течении 30 секунд он не возвращается на свое место(координаты) то принудительное телепортирование(запуск метода отдельного) его на домашние координаты

Comment: Сделал по совету из этого [вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445077/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так :

```
private boolean method() throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        //что то делает
    });

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    thread.start();
    long remainTime;
    while ((remainTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time) < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30)) 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(remainTime);

    return thread.isAlive();
}
```

Так же можно воспользоваться асинхронным вариантом:

```
private Future<Boolean> async() throws Exception {
    FutureTask<Boolean> result = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //основная работа

        return System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);
    });

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(result);
    return result;
}
```