# Как сделать GUI таймер в Java?

Tags: java, таймер

Нужен тикающий таймер вида.. минуты:секунды. 
0:00
0:01
0:02 ......

Comment: Для справки: [Таймер в методе java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445077/181472)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю `javafx` реализацию:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
        MyTask task = new MyTask( 10 );

        final Text clock = new Text();
        clock.textProperty().bind( task.messageProperty() );

        Thread th = new Thread( task );
        th.setDaemon( true );

        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new StackPane( clock ), 100, 30 ) );
        primaryStage.show();

        th.start();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch( args );
    }

    private class MyTask extends Task<Void> {
        private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "mm:ss" );
        private int end = 0;

        public MyTask( int endTime ) {
            this.end = i;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            int count = 0;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
                if ( count++ <= end ) {
                    updateMessage( dateFormat.format( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) );
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep( 1000 );
                    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

}
```

ну или анимация

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;

...

final Text clock = new Text();
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline( new KeyFrame( Duration.millis( 500 ), event -> {
    clock.setText( dateFormat.format( /*ваши вычисления*/ ) );
} ) );
timeline.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );
timeline.play();
```

Comment: Вот оно-то мне и надо. А то ругнулось на левый поток

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Answer (score 3):

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
         //тут вывод обновленного времени каждую секунду в нужный элемент 
    }));
timer.start();
```

Comment: да. уже нашел. спасибо )

Comment: @alex если ответ вам помог, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Создать поток, который будет обновлять поле в цикле, записывая туда текущее время.

Comment: Зачем создавать поток? Системный таймер, посылающий события в главный поток, прекрасно справляется с поставленной задачей.

Comment: Слушатель - тоже поток ;)

Comment: @Duoxx не согласен: Gleb явно отвечает на поставленный вопрос и ответ по смыслу подходит. Если вы считаете, что это некорректный ответ — пишите комментарии с конструктивной критикой.

Comment: В ответе идет описание алгоритма а на практике не показывается, я не спорю его ответ хороший.